# How to diagnose network failure properly on Ubuntu/Debian?

Tags: linux-networking, debian-jessie

I have a dedicated server from Online.net with Debian 8 Jessie and it's good, fast and everything is alright.

Well, until yesterday when i decided to do a restart, then I got prompted at my server Console that the network port is off!!

after hours and hours with support they were sure that the hardware is fine and it's configuration and software problem.

So my system will boot in rescue mode (which is it an Ubuntu system mounted on the network) so i can obtain a SSH and my server's disk will be then mounted on /mnt/sda1.

However, I've tried until now everything,

host file (/etc/hosts) is:

```
127.0.0.1 localhost
127.0.1.1 mydomain
```

Note that i've tried other combinations too with only 127.0.0.1 and also tried with my ip pointed to my domain but all the same

Hostname file (/etc/hostname):

```
mydomain
```

so i skipped the hassle with hosts because they look alright.

my interfaces file (/etc/network/interfaces):

```
# The loopback network interface
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

# The primary network interface
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet dhcp
```

I've tried too with static IP but to no avail.

Now the last respond from the support team was:

> It looks like the software on your server causes the network port being locked down because of the traffic patterns detected. 
>   You may try to use another distribution or another version of the kernel or network drivers to avoid the issue.

So what do you think? 
any tip will be highly appreciated.

thanks in advance

Comment: You should recover your data from the rescue mode, and then reinstall the system. It has probably been compromised.

Comment: Hi Michael, thanks for the fast reply, could you please tell me how did you come to this result that it's compromised, because of the lock down from the provider? and if i reinstall the system which is a receipe of death to me, what can i still backup to not affect the new instance,

Comment: The usual reason for online.net to lock out your network port is because some sort of abuse is coming from the server (spam, hacking attempts, etc). You should have been notified of this, or support should be more specific as to what is actually going on.

Comment: this is why did i asked you, because it's really not my case, my case is that my recent server 2 weeks ago got a hard disk failure and they have replaced it, now after 2 weeks until i've completely finished my setup and then BOoOm on the restart no network port. so i wasn't really online to attempt a malicious behaviour, and nothing came to me as an abuse at all, and somehow they aren't actually describing what's actually happening and answering very widely!!,

Comment: The phrase "because of the traffic patterns detected" means that either someone has compromised the system, or some of your applications generate abnormal traffic, and that is why their system locks the port.

Comment: then is it possible to start the system while blocking the networking from all softwares,?